# Find longest streak of consecutive months

Tags: stata

I have data on the profitability of different products every month:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float(id months)
1  6
1  7
1  8
1 10
1 11
1 13
1 14
1 15
1 16
1 17
2 10
2 11
2 12
2 16
2 17
2 18
2 19
2 21
2 22
2 25
end
```

The *community-contributed* command `tsspell` does not return correct results:

```
tsspell, f(L.months == .)
```

How can I find the longest streak of consecutive months for each product?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is puzzling as you don't substantiate the claim that `tsspell` does not return correct results. But `tsspell` does, so far as I can see, perform exactly as expected with your data example -- and its results match the solution of @Pearly Spencer.

```
tsset id months
tsspell, f(L.months == .)
egen longest = max(_seq), by(id)

list, sepby(id _spell)

     +----------------------------------------------+
     | id   months   _spell   _seq   _end   longest |
     |----------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1        6        1      1      0         5 |
  2. |  1        7        1      2      0         5 |
  3. |  1        8        1      3      1         5 |
     |----------------------------------------------|
  4. |  1       10        2      1      0         5 |
  5. |  1       11        2      2      1         5 |
     |----------------------------------------------|
  6. |  1       13        3      1      0         5 |
  7. |  1       14        3      2      0         5 |
  8. |  1       15        3      3      0         5 |
  9. |  1       16        3      4      0         5 |
 10. |  1       17        3      5      1         5 |
     |----------------------------------------------|
 11. |  2       10        1      1      0         4 |
 12. |  2       11        1      2      0         4 |
 13. |  2       12        1      3      1         4 |
     |----------------------------------------------|
 14. |  2       16        2      1      0         4 |
 15. |  2       17        2      2      0         4 |
 16. |  2       18        2      3      0         4 |
 17. |  2       19        2      4      1         4 |
     |----------------------------------------------|
 18. |  2       21        3      1      0         4 |
 19. |  2       22        3      2      1         4 |
     |----------------------------------------------|
 20. |  2       25        4      1      1         4 |
     +----------------------------------------------+
```